# Power calculation for non equi-sampled discrete signals

Tags: signals, sampling, period

Consider a discrete signal S sampled at point `x={2,5,9,11}`, whose respective values are `S(x)={300,312,340,400}`.

How would you calculate its power?
If it was an equi-sampled signal, with sampling period T=1, I would just calculate `sum(S^2(i))/N    with N=length(S(i))`.

Intuitively, I would calculate the power over a non equi-sampled sequence with something like:

`sum(S^2(x(i)))*(N-1)/(N*(x(N)-x(1)))`

In the example: `(300^2+312^2+340^2+400^2)*3/(4*(11-2))`

But I am not sure this is a general result.
Is there a well-known formula?

Comment: the first problem is you need to know how much time each measurement is representative of.once you can do that you just need to make a weighted average of the squared amplitude.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess each measurement with index i, excluding the ones on the edges is representative for `(x(i+1)-x(i-1))/2`. So you're saying that I should calculate:
`sum((x(i+1)-x(i-1))/2 * S^2(x(i)) / (x(N)-x(1)))` ?

Comment: yes, you may want th re-write you data duplicating the first and last results:  `x={2,2,5,9,11,11} , S(x)={300,300,312,340,400,400}` that way you have a x[n-1] and x[n+1] for the forst and last measurements